# kinetic and thermodynamic parameters of biodiesel production from lard

Tags: thermodynamics, biochemistry, kinetics

I want to know if someone has experimental results and calculations of the kinetic and thermodynamic parameters of Base Catalyzed Transesterification of pig fat, if not which is the method used to calculate them?

Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't expect a significant energy difference per ester bond between glyceryl and methyl esters of a fatty acid. The way to drive such a reaction forward is by removing the desired product as the reaction proceeds. Then more product will form as the system seeks a new equilibrium.